# Dissolving by two fields in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, dissolve

Is there a way in QGIS to dissolve a vector by two or more fields?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a new feature in QGIS 2.18.  [You can check the changelog here](http://changelog.qgis.org/en/qgis/version/2.18.0/#make-processing-dissolve-algorithm-accept-multiple).

*The dissolve algorithm now allows you to dissolve based on more than one field value. In previous QGIS versions a dissolve could only group features by a single field value.*

Comment: ... which is not available for OS X yet :-/

Comment: It looks like it is, depending on what installer package you want to use. Sadly I have zero experience with MACs so I don't know what's involved with that kind of installation

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work with ogr2ogr:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -dialect sqlite -sql "select st_union(geometry) as geometry,attribute_1 a,attribute_2 b from my_data group by a,b order by a,b" my_data.shp
```