# Merge shapes from the same layer by attributes

Tags: qgis, mergeshapes

I have a single layer with shapes (raster cells) that represent all countries on earth (the figure below shows france). Each shape has specific attributes.

[image]

Is it possible to merge the shapes by their attributes? E.g. if attributes x,y and z in shape 1 are the same as attributes x,y and z in shape 2 ... then create a shape that covers the area of shape 1 and shape 2 and contains the attributes x,y,z?

Example: If I have the attribute table displayed below, I would like to merge the shapes with the ID 2 and 7 to one shape.

[image]

*I have tens of thousands of shapes with hundreds if not thousands of different attributes. I'm afraid doing anything manually is not an option.*

Comment: can you give some more information about your data?  Which one is the 'base-layer.  And what data should be merged, etc...

Comment: Select those IDs and in digitize toolset use merge tool.

Comment: I have tens of thousands of shapes with hundreds if not thousands of different attributes. I'm afraid doing anything manually is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dissolve tool is what you're looking for (Vector -> Geoprocessing -> Dissolve).  This merges shapes with matching attributes into single shapes within the same layer. For QGIS 2.18 you can select a list of fields to dissolve by, rather than just one field as in the past.

This is the new dialogue - you can add multiple attributes and it will dissolve the shapes with matching combinations of attributes:
[image: Dissolve tool dialogue]

And this is the result - you can see how matching pairs of X/Y/Z are dissolved into single, multi-part shapes (Test is the original data):

[image: Dissolve results]

---

This question also has a suggestion for doing a multi-field dissolve in ogr2ogr which might be quicker as you could run that from the command line: [Dissolving by two fields in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216431/dissolving-by-two-fields-in-qgis)

Comment: I am looking for something that works for the same layer. Thanks, I'll check it out!

Comment: But with dissolve I cannot add 'criteria', can I? I only want to dissolve those shapes that share specific attributes with one another.

Comment: I added another figure to explain my question.

Comment: I see what you're trying to do. How many combinations of attributes have you got that you want to merge? For example in your figure above you've got Shape 1 (000) and Shapes 2 and 7 (111). If there aren't too many could you dissolve and then do some manual processing?

Comment: Thanks Ed! Your explanation is much clearer now. However, I also made a mistake in my question. How can I only merge/group those rows with the same attributes. e.g. row 2 and row 2 while row 1 would stay as there is no other row with the same values? ... similar to a JPEG compression

Comment: Jonas - the dissolve tool does that by default. If there are no other shapes with matching attributes then they get left alone; for example in my figure above shape ID 4 is unique and is left as an undissolved shape. I think a combo of my answer and also Kurt's answer from above is what you're looking for

Comment: Actually, you example does look pretty correct. I will try reproducing the same with my large table. Thanks for the support!

Comment: Worked! I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

FIRST Do the calculations in libre-office and add a new Field MERGE:
=IF(AND(B2=C2;C2=D2);1;0)

[image]

AFTERWARDS do a simple DISSOLVE in QGIS based on new field MERGE
1 = merge, 0 = do not merge

edit:
in an english libre-office you probably need to replace ; by ,:
=IF(AND(B2=C2,C2=D2),1,0)

Comment: Not exactly what I had in mind but I guess this would indeed work!

Answer (score 0):

You could select the desired features based upon their attributes, save them to a new shape/layer and then merge the new layers.

Or you could build a graphical model which omits the saving of a new layer, but otherwise does the same.

Comment: I have tens of thousands of shapes with hundreds if not thousands of different attributes. I'm afraid doing anything manually is not an option.

Comment: Well, then run a model. Or revert to python. Problem is, that we do not know your data structure and your final goal.

Answer (score 0):

I think that only a reasonable answer would be, select attribute values from both layer with expression, then save them separate and merge them.
[image]